# Turning Off Grouping In ObjectListView Turns Of Sorting

Tags: vb.net, sorting, objectlistview

I am struggling to find information on a lot of small issues I'm starting to come across since recently integrating the ObjectListView into my application.  I must admit, I love the control and it takes a lot of work away from me by having the control pretty much do everything that I need.

However, amongst a few issues that I've come across thus far, one is the fact that if I turn off grouping for individual columns it no longer allows me to sort these columns.

For example, my ListView control has an ID, Summary, Location, etc., etc.  I currently run grouping on the ID because I attach a unique footer against every ID and it looks good.  But, when I click on Summary, or Location it then groups all items by Summary or Location and therefore I end up with the group header but no footer anymore because the footer no longer corresponds with the ID.

What I want to achieve is to allow the user to click on any other column, but still maintain the group by ID and thus keep the footer against each item.  I only want the items to sort, not group, but as mentioned, when I turn off the grouping against each column, it turns off the sort function.

**UPDATE**

Basically, looking at the screenshot below, I want to be able to click on the Priority Column Header (for example) to sort the list of object by Priority, but still maintain the Group By Ticket (with the Group Footer details).  And basically be able to click on any Column header to sort the list but keeping the grouping by Ticket.

[image]

I have intercepted the OLV_BeforeCreatingGroups event to add:

```
e.Parameters.GroupByColumn = Ticket_ID
```

This now seems to maintain my grouping by Ticket no matter what Column header I click on, but I now loose the sort functionality.

Comment: What do you have `AlwaysGroupBySortOrder`set to? Is says: "If AlwaysGroupByColumn is not null, this property will be used to decide how those groups are sorted. If this property has the value SortOrder.None, then the sort order will toggle according to the users last header click.". So you probably should set `AlwaysGroupByColumn` to `Ticket_ID` and `AlwaysGroupBySortOrder` to `SortOrder.None`?

Comment: I have tried those settings, but it doesn't seem to help.  Setting the `AlwaysGroupByColumn` allows me to maintain my group footers for every column header clicked, but it removes all sort capability from the control.  Clicking on the column headers (twice as the first time does nothing) only seems to reverse the order of the list, not actually sort it.

Comment: @Riples Any chance you could share how you formatted your priority column with the cool colors?  I'm looking to do the same thing.

Comment: Sure @malt_man.  I used the `ObjectListView_FormatCell` event to override the cell painting for each item.  I ran a select statement on `e.ColumnIndex` to determine which column I wanted to override and then  another select statement on `e.SubItem.Text` to obtain the cell text.  Then I simply used `e.SubItem.BackColor` and `e.SubItem.ForeColor` to change the visuals of each cell based on the cell text.  Make sure you have `UseCellFormatEvents` turned on for the control and `OwnerDraw`.  Hope that helps, if not maybe contact me and I can try and help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `AlwaysGroupByColumn` to be the TicketId column. That will do the trick :)

Second attempt:

Thanks for the screenshot. I think I understand what you want. You are hoping that clicking on the header will sort the groups themselves. That's not the default behaviour, which is to sort the rows within each group.

To do what you are asking:

1. Listen for `BeforeCreatingGroups` event and fill in the `GroupComparer` property on the event argument block. This comparer controls the ordering of the groups.
2. The default group order is based on `OLVGroup.SortValue`. So you could install a `GroupFormatter` delegate and change the `SortValue` for each group so they are ordered in the manner you want.

In either case, you will need to use `PrimarySort` and `PrimarySortOrder` to know which column the user last clicked.

Comment: Hi Grammarian, thanks for the reply.  I am unable to find the AlwaysSortByColumn method as you have suggested.  I can only find AlwaysGroupByColumn and AlwaysGroupBySortOrder.  Could you please elaborate further on your reply thankyou.

Comment: Just to provide more detail - the AlwaysGroupByColumn does allow me to maintain the same group on every column, but it won't sort correctly when clicking on a column.

Comment: Sorry, I did mean AlwaysGroupByColumn. When AlwaysGroupByColumn is set, clicking on header will sort rows within each group.

Comment: Your "groups" consist of a single row? I think you may have misunderstood what groups will do. Groups collect the rows into "subcollections" under a heading. Clicking on the column header changes the order of items in the subcollection.

Comment: Yeah I do understand how groups work (I think), but I guess I was hoping that the ObjectListView could handle something like that.  Do you know if there is any other way I can create a footer like comment for each item in a listview? Or is there a possibility of adding such a feature to ObjectListView?  I love the footer capability and it really suits the functionality of what I am trying to do, but I really don't know how to get around it without losing the sort feature of the ListView.  I really don't want to use a treeview though if possible.

Comment: I have since modified my application to not handle the group footers like I originally intended.  It was obvious that I was trying to do some irregular behavior by the ListView that wasn't supported, therefore, I have since reneged on the original request and reverted back to normal group handling of the control.  I appreciate your time to comment on an alternative method for group handling.  Thanks